# Can $\langle x,x \rangle$ be less than zero on an inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

We define an inner product on a vector space $V$ such that for all $x,y,z \in V$ and for all $c \in F$ the following four properties are satisfied:

1. $\langle x+y,z \rangle = \langle x,z \rangle + \langle y,z \rangle $
2. $\langle cx,y \rangle = c\langle x,y \rangle$
3. $\langle x,y \rangle = \overline {\langle y,x \rangle}$
4. $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ if $x \neq 0$

But the contraposition of property 4 is: $x = 0$ if $\langle x,x \rangle \le 0$. And there is a theorem: $\langle x,x \rangle = 0$ if and only if $x=0$.

I can understand that $\langle x,x \rangle = 0$ if $x=0$, but for $x=0$ if $\langle x,x \rangle = 0$, what if $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$? I mean $x=0$ if $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$.

I want to know

1. Is there any $x$ that satisfies $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$?
2. Or if it does not exist, how can I prove that $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$ doesn't exist?

Comment: No, there is no such $x$, that's exactly what the fourth point says.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Then, how can I prove it?

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle in place of < and > when writing out inner products.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks, I thought <> works for inner product... sorry

Comment: @JAEMTO It's okay! A lot of people make the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have $x\in V$ such that $\langle x,x\rangle \leq 0$. We will prove that then we must have both $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$ and $x=0_V$ *(I denote the zero element of $V$ by $0_V$ to avoid confusion with the scalar $0\in\mathbb{R}$)*.

- From (the contrapositive of) 4., you know that $x=0_V$, as "if $x\neq 0_V$ then $\langle x,x\rangle > 0$."
- But $0_v = c\cdot 0_v$ for $c=0$, so applying 2. we get 
  $$
  \langle x,x\rangle = \langle cx,x\rangle = c\langle x,x\rangle = 0\langle x,x\rangle = 0
  $$
  and therefore $\langle x,x\rangle=0$.

To summarize, for any $x\in V$ we have that $\langle x,x\rangle \leq 0$ implies ($x=0_V$ and $\langle x,x\rangle =0$). So there is no $x\in V$ such that $\langle x,x\rangle < 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand my question thoroughly now!

Answer (score 2):

Point 4 says: if $x\neq 0$, then $\langle x,x\rangle > 0$. As you observe, $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$ iff $x = 0$. So this immediately answers your question 1: Break into two cases, $x\neq 0$ and $x=0$. In the first case, $\langle x,x\rangle > 0$. In the second case, $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$. In neither case do we have $\langle x,x\rangle < 0$, and the cases exhausted the vector space, so we have your desired result.

(Note that if we remove the fourth hypothesis, we generalize to what are called indefinite inner products. These are important in the theory of relativity. See more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space).)

Comment: So, you mean that my question 2 can be proved by the theorem I wrote?
and what 'drop' mean on note?

Comment: "Drop" here means "if we decide not to ask for the fourth condition, in the definition."

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer